# Как добавить к URL выбраные параметры из нескольких списков input и перейти по нему?

Tags: javascript, html

Нужна помощь с переходом по выбраному урл.
У меня три списка - день, месяц, год.
При выборе дат из этого списка и нажатии на кнопу Sumbit нас должно направить на страницу вида [http://Адрес_сайта/2018/06/26/](http://%D0%90%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81_%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0/2018/06/26/)
Подскажите как это сделать без обработчика, а просто повесив событие на **onclick="???"** 
(здесь я предполагаю должен быть опрос наподобии document.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value только чтобы сплюсовал (учитывал) все три поля при формировании урл.)
Это необходимо для быстрой навигации по архивам вордпресс.
Получалось переходить только по одному полю. Подскажите как собрать значения трех полей через / и добавить это к урл главной?
Переход по нажатию на кнопку.

```html
<form action="/" method="post" name="calend_form">
<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1"><tbody><tr><td><select name="day" size="1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
</select></td><td><select name="month" size="1">
  <option value="01">январь</option>
<option value="02">февраль</option>
<option value="03">март</option>
<option value="04">апрель</option>
<option value="05">май</option>
<option value="06">июнь</option>
<option value="07">июль</option>
<option value="08">август</option>
<option value="09">сентябрь</option>
<option value="10">октябрь</option>
<option value="11">ноябрь</option>
<option value="12">декабрь</option>
</select></td><td><select name="year" size="1">
  <option value="2002">2002</option>
<option value="2003">2003</option>
<option value="2004">2004</option>
<option value="2005">2005</option>
<option value="2006">2006</option>
<option value="2007">2007</option>
<option value="2008">2008</option>
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option>
<option value="2014">2014</option>
<option value="2015">2015</option>
<option value="2016">2016</option>
<option value="2017">2017</option>
<option value="2018" >2018</option>
 </select></td><td align="right"><!--colspan="2" --><input type="submit" name="Calend_ok" onclick="???" value="Искать"></td></tr></tbody></table></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!String.prototype.padStart) {
    String.prototype.padStart = function padStart(targetLength,padString) {
        targetLength = targetLength>>0; //floor if number or convert non-number to 0;
        padString = String(padString || ' ');
        if (this.length > targetLength) {
            return String(this);
        }
        else {
            targetLength = targetLength-this.length;
            if (targetLength > padString.length) {
                padString += padString.repeat(targetLength/padString.length); //append to original to ensure we are longer than needed
            }
            return padString.slice(0,targetLength) + String(this);
        }
    };
}
(function($){
    $(document).on('submit', 'form[name="calend_form"]', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            day = parseInt($('[name="day"]', $this).val()),
            month = parseInt($('[name="month"]', $this).val()),
            year = parseInt($('[name="year"]', $this).val());
            if(day && month && year){
                window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/" + String(year) + "/" + String(month).padStart(2, '0') + "/" + String(day).padStart(2, '0') + "/";
            }
        return !1;
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый ответ. Все работает. Оказалось сложнее чем предполагалось). Сам бы такое не решил. По коду, вторая часть ловит событие sumbit в конкретной форме и направляет по указаному урл. А для чего служит первая часть кода? Определяет символы для заполнения или длинну?

Comment: @Максим, Это полифил на пока экспериментальный метод. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart Это по сути аналогия на str_pad в php http://php.net/manual/ru/function.str-pad.php. Почему не брать хорошее для исполнения)))